# PRISM Modular dependencies

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a question regarding module dependencies to other module. I have researched regarding about how different modules communicate with each other but I am not sure what to use and I quite need some clarifications how am I going to use them properly.

- How do I load modules depending with each other? e.g. `Module A` needs to navigate to `Module B` one of the views of it. Should I load `Module A` first and then load `Module B` when I need to navigate to it?
- How do I set dependencies with each module? Should I configure them inside the `ModuleCatalog` resulting into `moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleB>("ModuleB", InitializationMode.OnDemand, "ModuleA");` or should I do: `[ModuleDependency(ModuleA)]` on top of the `Module B` class
- `Module A` needs to navigate to one of the pages in `Module B` and I have to pass navigation parameters into `Module B`. Should I use a `shared service` or an `event aggregator` ? though as much as possible I want to lessen the use of an `event aggregator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the beauty of Prism in my opinion.

You have a lot of flexibility when it comes to where to load the modules.

In the past, I have used the [IModuleManager](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Modularity/ModuleManager.cs) which I can inject into a ViewModel of any module and from there I can call the Load Method.

The load method takes in the string name of the module that you have registered.
When registering I have also set the Load Type to onDemand so the module is only loaded only when I specifically call the load method.

So in your scenario, you could load Module B whenever you need to in Module A.
It could be triggered by some business logic for your application.

To answer your second question you can then simply just pass your parameters using the navigation parameters functionality of the Navigation service

```
var param = new NavigationParameters();
param.Add("trip", someObject);    
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("TripDetailsPage", param);
```

EDIT:

So if you want to know whether a Module has been loaded or not you could do something like the following:

```
public class ModuleService : IModuleService
{
    private readonly IModuleCatalog _moduleCatalog;
    private readonly IModuleManager _moduleManager;


    public ModuleService(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, IModuleManager moduleManager)
    {
        _moduleCatalog = moduleCatalog;
        _moduleManager = moduleManager;

    }

    public bool Exists(string moduleName)
    {
        return _moduleCatalog.Modules.Any(x => x.ModuleName == moduleName);
    }

    public bool Initialized(string moduleName)
    {
        return _moduleCatalog.Modules.Any(x => x.ModuleName == moduleName && x.State == ModuleState.Initialized);
    }

    public void LoadModule(string moduleName)
    {
        _moduleManager.LoadModule(moduleName);
    }                    
}
```

So by combining the functionality of the ModuleManager and the Module Catalog, I can check if a module is already loaded using the modules [ModuleState](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Modularity/ModuleState.cs) property

Comment: I see, but the thing is, do prism have any capabilities to know when the module has been previously loaded so that I wouldn't call `Module.Load("ModuleName")` every time.

Comment: @Swift_Talt Yes you can I will edit my answer to describe in detail